# Django Intermediary model save() issue

Tags: django, cpython

This issue is similar to these [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387686/what-are-the-steps-to-make-a-modelform-work-with-a-manytomany-relationship-with-a) and [b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091328/django-cannot-set-values-on-a-manytomanyfield-which-specifies-an-intermediary-mod) ,but little different. I am new to django,so please bear with me. Below are my models

```
class Project(UniqueIdentifier):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2)

class User(UniqueIdentifier):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False,null=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False,null=False)
    email_address = models.EmailField(max_length=200)
    user_state = models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Employee(User):
    experience = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    userType = models.CharField(max_length=2,choices=USER_TYPES)

class Team(UniqueIdentifier):
    role = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Employee, through="TeamMember")
    belongsTo = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name="team")

class TeamMember(UniqueIdentifier):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    members = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
```

and in my generic view class

```
class ProjectView(UpdateView):
    model = Project
    fset = inlineformset_factory(Project,Team,form=TeamForm,can_delete=False,fk_name="belongsTo",extra=0)
    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        c = get_object_or_404(Project, unique_id = self.kwargs.get('cid'))
        df = ProjectForm(instance=c)
        .......
        return c

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProjectUpdateView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs) 
        ..........
        return context

    def form_valid(self,form,*args, **kwargs):
        c = get_object_or_404(Project, unique_id = self.kwargs.get('cid'))
        if self.request.method == "POST":
            df = ProjectForm(self.request.POST, instance = c)
            if df.is_valid():
                c = df.save()
                fs = self.fset(self.request.POST,instance=c)
                if fs.is_valid():
                    k=fs.save()
```

and i am getting this error.

```
Cannot set values on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model.
```

Please suggest if someone has alternative solution (i really don't want to spilt the logic into separate form). Appreciate your help, thanks!

** Updated: Found soluton [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074938/django-m2m-form-save-through-table/3125398#3125398). Here is my solution,

```
Class ProjectView(CreateView):
    .........
    def form_valid():
        .........
        if fs.is_valid():
                    k=fs.save(commit=False)
                    for h in k:
                        h.save()
                    for x in range(0,len(k)):
                        for y in self.request.POST.getlist('team-'+str(x)+'-members'):
                            p=TeamMember(team=k[x],members=get_object_or_404(Employee,unique_id=y))
                            p.save()
```

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

It would be helpful if you had included a stacktrace (instead of just the error).  But from the looks of it, you need to save instances of the intermediate model:

Quoting from [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships):

> Now that you have set up your ManyToManyField to use your intermediary model, you're ready to start creating some many-to-many relationships. You do this by creating instances of the intermediate model ... Unlike normal many-to-many fields, you can't use add, create, or assignment to create relationships ... The only way to create this type of relationship is to create instances of the intermediate model.