# add() for ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model

Tags: django, django-models

There are many questions about this Exception:

```
AttributeError: Cannot set values on a ManyToManyField which specifies 
an intermediary model.
Use myapp.MyThroughModel's Manager instead.
```

The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)

> You can’t just create a relationship between a Person and a Group -
>   you need to specify all the detail for the relationship required by
>   the Membership model. The simple add, create and assignment calls
>   don’t provide a way to specify this extra detail. As a result, they
>   are disabled for many-to-many relationships that use an intermediate
>   model.

But all my attributes/columns of MyThroughModel are optional. The manager could create them.

How can I write a custom manager to automatically create MyThroughModel instances?

I need a solution at ORM-level, not Form-level.

Answer (score 7):

I found a way to tell django to ignore the extra data:

```
class MyThroughModel(Model):
    class Meta():
        auto_created=True
    ...
```

**Update**

This creates issues with the django internal migrations. We updated our code and don't use `auto_created = True` any more.

Comment: For me, this solution breaks migrations. makemigrations wants to remove the through model with this option set.

Comment: @RobinElvin which version of django do you use?

Comment: so what do you do now?

Comment: I refactored it. The MyThroughModel was removed and the relevant class uses a normal ManyToManyField now. We don't need the intermediary model. It was a design mistake.

Comment: auto_create=True  may work if you have a legacy DB (where you have no option but to use a through_model) and the tables are "unmanaged" (no migrations).  So long as the intermediate table either has no extra fields or all fields have defaults.  This solution is a bit of a hack, but it may save a fair bit of complicated code needed to save and update M2M relations manually.

Comment: Highly advise against this solution, it causes very bizarre behavior with the migrator. AND it doesnt actually result in the add behavior working.

Comment: @NickBL could you please elaborate " it doesnt actually result in the add behavior working."?

Comment: I ran into the same django internal migrations problems I believe you were referencing in your Update. When i added it, the makemigrations utility started ignoring the "through" tag on the dependent models and it generated its own internal through tables (which led me to have 2 through tables, one made by django and the original legacy one). It also failed to auto create rows in the through table it created.